# Returning a view from a helper class in Mvc 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a try - catch segment in a helper class. I want to return a view if the try catch segment throws an error. Now I  have:

```
try
{
    //some code
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml");
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you asking here?

Comment: I want to return the view ~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml
Since I am in a helperclass and not a controller, 
    return View("~/Views/Home/Index.cshtml"); doesn't work

Comment: Are you allowed to throw the exception back up to the controller so it can handle it and do the redirection?

Comment: Yes, but I don't know how to do that :)

Comment: Can you post the controller code that is calling this helper class please?

Comment: I am calling the helper class directly from the view. If there is a way to call a controller from the helper class that would be great.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways:
1. (Re)throw the exception in the helper + add exception handling to the controller, or
2. Catch exception in the helper, return e.g. a bool to signal success/failure + respond to this value in the controller.

*1st approach:*

**MyController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    try
    {
        MyHelper.SomeMethod(); // This method is allowed to throw
        return View(); // No view name specified means this renders "Index"
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

*2nd approach:*

**MyController.cs**

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    bool succeeded = MyHelper.SomeFunction(); // This method should never throw
    if (succeeded)
        return View(); // No view name specified means this renders "Index"
    else
        return View("Error");
}
```

Also, try to avoid calling helpers in your View, unless your View can handle all their results. When a View is already executing you can't simply 'switch' it to another view, that would be the task and the responsibility of the Controller.

Comment: The problem is that the exception might happen when a user clicks a button in the index view. I could probably solve this by using a partial view, but i would prefer not to. Is there any way to call a controller from the helper class?(The project is already spaghetti code, so it doesn't have to be best practise)

Comment: I think i found a way to use your method. Let me just test it :)

Comment: Worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
try
{

}
catch (System.Exception)
{
    return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
```

Comment: I get the message Redirect to action does not exist in the current context. Probably because I am not in a controller but in a helper class.

Comment: You should try , catch and redirect from a controller.

Comment: I don't dare to do that in this instance. I am using System.Xml;
and System.ServiceModel.Syndication;. When I started a new project VS had problems finding the correct version of system.xml so now I don't dare to touch that segment of the code. probably too paranoid :)

Comment: You cannot redirect from outside the request context. If you are in a request context, you have a controller who can manage your error.